# Generic extension method, List(Of T)

Tags: vb.net, generics, extension-methods

I am simply trying to spit out a string which aggregates a List's values into a NewLine delimited string.

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToColumn(Of T)(ByVal source As IEnumerable(Of T)) As String
    ' assuming Aggregate(Of String) will be inefficient, using StringBuilder
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each val As T In source
        sb.Append(val.ToString() & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

This method will help while debugging to see the entire contents of a List, while `?source` only spits out the first 100 elements in the immediate window (maybe there is a different way to do this?). I just want to be able to copy it over to something like Excel quickly for analysis.

The problem is that although this method compiles, in usage, it is not recognized as an extension of List(of T) i.e.

```
Dim result As Int32()
Debug.Print(result.ToList().ToColumn())
' this line doesn't compile:
' 'toColumn' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)'
```

I'd like to reuse this method on anything which I can box into an Object and get .ToString() (everything!), hence the generic aspect of it. I have seen many people add constraints to the generic T, i.e. `Where T : Constraint`, but my constraint would be Object, as is the nature of this method, which doesn't compile.

My question is why isn't it recognized as an extension of List(Of Integer). Also, is what I want to achieve possible?

Comment: Is your extension method in a module that is in scope in those places?

Comment: How are you adding the method? The native VBA implementation in Excel is based on VB6. You need to make this as a VSTO component to use .Net.

Comment: Review [Extension Methods (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) and ensure you are following all of the rules (declared in a Module, etc). Your code, what is visible of it, is correct.

Comment: @JimWooley - Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: To test if your extension method is in scope, try calling `ModuleName.ToColumn(result.ToList())`. You should be able to reference the method explicitly (note that it might not be visible in your intellisense, but the code should compile). If you are getting errors, you may have forgotten an `Import` statement, or your Module might not be `Public`, etc.

Comment: @vcsjones Doh! It wasn't in scope. I've been spoiled by VS giving suggestions as to `Imports` I should make when neglect to add it. I guess it doesn't do that for extension methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using an extension method on `List(Of T)` instead of `IEnumerable(Of T)`, like this:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function ToColumn(Of T)(ByVal source As List(Of T)) As String
    ' assuming Aggregate(Of String) will be inefficient, using StringBuilder
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each val As T In source
        sb.Append(val.ToString() & Environment.NewLine)
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Comment: `List(Of T)` [implements `IEnumerable(Of T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx?cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) - it makes no difference when using with a `List(Of T)` and building the method with `IEnumerable(Of T)` makes it more widely useful.

Comment: Rather than change source to List(T), why not just modify the implementing code to use `Debug.Print(result.ToColumn())` and avoid the List conversion entirely? You shouldn't need the List unless you are doing things you can't through the IEnumerable interface (.add/.Remove)

Comment: @JimWooley I've changed my code to the more concise `result.ToColumn()`. `ToList()` was a remnant of my debugging efforts and, as @Cyborgx37 pointed out, it makes no difference because of the inheritance. Thank you.